# Apache Solr Search

Tags: apache, search, solr

I'm encountering some problems with my Solr search plateform (which is in 4.7) in my eZ Publish CMS (5.3.3).

When customer wants to find the word "Molecular" and type the half of it ("Molecu"), the search plateform can't find the associated content.
Another example of a half word which isn't working : "Plateform" and "plate".

Do you know some functions or configurations I have to add to my Solr to get such behaviour ?

I've already tested snowballPorterFilterFactory and EdgeNGramFilterFactory, without success...

Thanks in advance !

Best regards,

Comment: Have you reindexed after you changed the definitions? The EdgeNGramFilter is made for this purpose, but it has to actually create ngrams of the size you expect. There's also the Suggester which implements functionality like this.

Comment: Yes I reindexed after your comment, but it didn't change anything ..

Comment: Use the Analysis page under Solr Admin to see exactly what values are generated on both sides - include that and your field definition in the question.

Comment: Ye thanks @MatsLindh I was able to check what was going on with my solr, and i realize I was using the filter on both query and index !